# Flush stream from .NET Controller to send a large file in chunks

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to send a large file from a .NET Controller. The file is a large one which I have to first download from one source and then send to the client. The problem is that my code is not flushing it properly, the entire file appears as a whole only after the controller method is exited.
Some pseudocode

```
public async Task ChunkDownloadTest()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "file/octet-stream";
            Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "mytestfile.txt" }.ToString());
            await Response.StartAsync();
            for (int i =0; i < 1000; i ++)
            {
                var content = "MyChunkDownloadTest\n";
                var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
                using var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                await Response.WriteAsync(reader.ReadToEnd());
                await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                await stream.FlushAsync();
                reader.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

What I expect is that after each loop the data should be flushed and downloaded by the client so if I somehow pause this operation at i = 500 then there should be a partially downloaded file with 500 lines and once I resume the operation rest of the file download should continue.
Can someone guide me at what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you reading the response on the client's end?

Comment: For test I am trying to download it directly from browser.

Comment: And how do you observe the behaviour?

Comment: By adding delay after each loop or breakpoint.

Comment: Your browser most likely won't let you access the file until the download is completed though. The test is flawed.